# Datagridview transfer selected rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, transfer

How can I transfer selected rows from datagridview to another datagridview in another form? I'm having trouble with this.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried? Just as an idea, I'd use the new form's parameters to pass the selected rows to the new form.

Comment: MoveData(EmployeeRecords, frmArchive.EmployeeRecordsDataGridView)
This is my problem. I don't know what is the right code to place here. Should I place it in the button that I created or on the event Form_Load?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that in in one of [gridview event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library). I would use

```
RowCommand  Occurs when a button is clicked in a GridView control.
```

But you can do it any other event that meets your needs. Both the Gridview must be on same page so you can access them from code behind. You can access any control on the page using code behind, including GridView. You should be able to add contents/remove contents as needed.  Make sure you issue databaind on both gridviews so they are rendered fresh after the changes. So basically you need code behind :)

Comment: I have a button and when I press that button the selected data would transfer into another datagridview in another form. Is that possible?

Comment: @user3172293, two things. 1, jsyk, you can edit (and delete) comments, and if you comment below someone's post, it will automatically alert them. 2, and yes, what you asked it possible.

Comment: @user3172293 yes you ca do that. It need to be implemented with code behind. If they two gridview are on same page, should not be a problem.

Comment: I have two forms, both with datagridview and I want to transfer the selected rows in form1 to form2. But I'm having trouble with it.
I don't know what's the right syntax here.
 MoveData(EmployeeRecords, frmArchive.EmployeeRecordsDataGridView)